# PGM Mysql PDO WHEN or IF STATEMENT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to have a WHEN statement or IF Statement within a PDO Statement? I've tried the following but it does not work

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT company_id, name, alias, fk_company_type as type, is_active as active FROM company WHERE (CASE WHEN :srchBy = "alias" THEN alias ELSE name END)  LIKE :srchField');

$stmt->bindParam(':srchBy', $srchBy, PDO::PARAM_INT); //bind :srchField to $srchField in sql statement
$stmt->bindParam(':srchField', $srchField, PDO::PARAM_INT); //bind :srchField to $srchField in sql statement
```

Table Structure

```
company_id      |23980471998218241  | 23980471998218242       |
fk_company_type |HQ                 |SITE                     |
name            |JOHN PLUMBING HQ   |JOHN PLUMBING - BRIDGE ST| 
alias           |CITY RD HQ         |BRIDGE ST SERVICE        |
is_active       |1                  |1                        | 
created_date    |2015-04-18 19:35:32|2015-04-18 19:34:46      |
```

Comment: where have you put bind params? please paste complete code.

Comment: fyi: you cannot bind identifiers (table/column)

Comment: Code pasted with bind params. Thanks so if I am correct I can't conditionally change the column or table properties within a statement?

Comment: case statement should be `CASE WHEN col = "alias" THEN alias  LIKE :srchField ELSE name  LIKE :srchField END)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't bind parameters by column names. but you can do other way

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT company_id, name, alias, fk_company_type as type, is_active as active FROM company WHERE (CASE WHEN "'.$srchBy.'" = "alias" THEN alias ELSE name END)  LIKE ?');
$stmt->bindValue(1, "%$srchField%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

Every operator/identifier must be hardcoded but if that's not case you need to validate identifier

Comment: Thanks I gave it a go. But I am getting an undefined return. To debug I've defined $srchBy = "alias";     Also if I replace {$srchBy} = "alias" with 1=1, it works so the CASE statement seems fine. So it must be to do with the $srchBy condition. Any thoughts?

Comment: @KaTech can you please paste table structure above along with some possible value for srchBy.   seems case syntax is wrong.

Comment: @kemlesh I've added the table structure and values. Hope this helps and thanks in advanced.

Comment: Also I have the following:$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: Fantastic this works. I really appreciate the effort you have put into this. Being able to do these conditions within mysql really saves alot of unessary coding. THANK YOU!